# Engagespot overrides the material-icon's custom css

Tags: css, angular, import, stylesheet, google-material-icons

While implementing the notifications via [EngagesSpot](https://engagespot.co/). It adds two stylesheets one for engagespot and another one for fonts.

As displayed in the below picture:

[image]

Due to this,(fonts style-sheet >> https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,200,400").Custom css gets distorted. 
Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's the Google font that's breaking your CSS. Some CSS properties in the engagespot.css file might be overriding your CSS. We'll be soon releasing an update that fixes these CSS issues for some websites.

Comment: Yes. This is happening because of the font-weight which by-default provided by engagespot is light.If default is set to normal,I guess this problem can be solved.Hope this helps

Comment: @AyushiVerma, Engagespot now has better integration with React and other JS frameworks - See https://npmjs.com/package/@engagespot/react-component

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have syntax error, get rid of extra `rel="stylesheet"`

[image]

Comment: This is injected dynamically by engagespot's script.Can't edit this.Any other way?